# Microsoft Graph API: What is the error code and exception in the Java SDK for a invalid refresh token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am requesting an access token with a refresh token and I would like to try handle for an expired token.

I am not in a position to revoke the refresh tokens for my test accounts to try figure it out.

I have tried giving an invalid refresh token biut it gives the error

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: ecf9fec9-b75c-4b4c-9c74-70273e6d1b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 44946f49-bb25-450d-86d3-121d3f279f21\r\nTimestamp: 2019-07-24 16:15:20Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2019-07-24 16:15:20Z","trace_id":"ecf9fec9-b75c-4b4c-9c74-70273e6d1b00","correlation_id":"44946f49-bb25-450d-86d3-121d3f279f21"}
```

Obviously it is detecting it as a not a valid refresh token apposed to an expired token

Answer (score 1):

We have recently updated our documentation to help with getting access tokens.

To ensure you have the latest check out these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk

To initiate the client https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=Java

Like this

```
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_GUID, NATIONAL_CLOUD);

IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();
```

And you'll want to decide which provider you need here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider

likely this one

```
AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(
                                                    clientId,
                                                    scopes,
                                                    authorizationCode,
                                                    redirectUri,
                                                    clientSecret);
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I think you have misunderstood my question. I can request the tokens I need with graph no problem. I am wondering what error graph returns if I provide a revoked refresh token when I ask for an access token using said refresh token?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a best practice to work against classes of error. For example, the usual response to a expired refresh token would be to require user interaction and the user authenticates again. Our MSAL libraries would throw a user interaction required exception and then you app would call to acquire the token needed interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Identity has documentation on the refresh tokens here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

and a list of error codes here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#error-codes-for-token-endpoint-errors